# Javascript add item in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

this is my code

```
    var arr = [{
      id: '1',
      total: "Total:",
      titlea: 'a',
      titleb: 'b',
   }];

    let c=  {titlec: 'c'}
    arr.push(c);
    console.log(arr)
```

So the console.log shows that

```
0: {id: "1", totalPdf: "Total:", titlea: "a", titleb: "b"}
1: {titlec: "c"}
```

But I want it as:

```
0: {id: "1", totalPdf: "Total:", titlea: "a", titleb: "b", titlec: "c"}
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Look up how to assign properties to objects.

Comment: `arr[0].titlec="c"` or its equal `arr[0]["titlec"]="c"`

Comment: Do you want `0: {id: "1", totalPdf: "Total:", titlea: "a", titleb: "b", titlec: "c"}` or `{id: "1", totalPdf: "Total:", titlea: "a", titleb: "b", titlec: "c"}`?

Answer (score 3):

Iterate over your data set using `.forEach()` or `.map()` and use `Object.assign()` to add properties of the `c` object to objects in array.

```js
let arr = [{
  id: '1',
  total: "Total:",
  titlea: 'a',
  titleb: 'b',
}];

let c =  {titlec: 'c'}

arr.forEach(o => Object.assign(o, c));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let key = Object.keys(c)[0];
let value = c.titlec;
arr[0][key] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr.push(c);` will push a new element to the object.Instead use array `map` &  `Object.assign`.Array `map` will return a new array and with updated object value

```js
var arr = [{
  id: '1',
  total: "Total:",
  titlea: 'a',
  titleb: 'b',
}];

let c = {
  titlec: 'c'
}

let m = arr.map(function(item) {
  return Object.assign(item, c)

})
console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

`push()` will add a new element to the array,you should not use it

```js
    var arr = [{
      id: '1',
      total: "Total:",
      titlea: 'a',
      titleb: 'b',
   }];

    let c=  {titlec: 'c'}
    for(var i in c){
       arr[0][i]=c[i];
    }
    console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Why the loop? .

Comment: @mplungjan My answer is suppose  object `c` has many properties

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arr = [{
          id: '1',
          total: "Total:",
          titlea: 'a',
          titleb: 'b',
       }];

    arr[0]["titlec"] = "c";
    console.log(arr)
```

Comment: This seems to be hard coding

Comment: this is not a generic solution.

Comment: I already tried this, but i don't think this is a good way, but thank you

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is needed for only single use you can use by using the below simple code it will work correctly without using any loop statement.
    `arr[0]['titlec'] = c.titlec`